# Calling a custom WCF application from a SharePoint 2010 Web Part

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

All,

I created a WCF application that interacts with data in a database.  I also created a new visual web part that consumes it.

I also created an ASP.NET application that calls the web part the exact way.

The web part does not work, it gets the following message, however the ASP.NET application does work.

> Could not find default endpoint
>   element that references contract
>   'ServiceReference1.IService'
>   in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be
>   because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because
>   no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client
>   element.

Answer (score 1):

lol, that was quick... I found the answer... I had one last thing that I wanted to try first before I did anything else.

I coppied the code that was in the app.config in my VisualWebPart project into the  area in the sharepoints web.config file.